# How to loop over multiple json array and display in angular js

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a new school management system and I want to display the list of department and courses the department is offering, I actually save the course in JSON format in the database

This is my JSON response

```
[
    {"course_code":"PHP101","course_title":"Introduction to Physics"},
    {"course_code":"PHP101d","course_title":"dkndk"},
    {"course_code":"PHP1091","course_title":"Introduction to House"}
]
```

my course conponnent.html

```
<table id="responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Courses</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let emp of table_list" class="gradeX">
        <td>{{emp_id}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.course_code}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.level}}</td>
        <td>
            <li *ngFor="let ok of emp.department_course">
                {{ok}}
            </li>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my component.ts

```
fetch() {
    this._userService.generalInfo().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.table_list = response._data;
    });
}
```

this are my result so far

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ham1x.png]

Comment: Are you sure that you've provided the correct response? I can see only a single array objects. Please update it. Just console log `this.table_list` right after getting value and show.

Comment: 0:
department_course: "[{"course_code":"PHP101","course_title":"Introduction to Physics"},{"course_code":"PHP101d","course_title":"dkndk"},{"course_code":"PHP1091","course_title":"Introduction to House"}]"
department_name: "Department of Physics Electronics"
id: 1
level: "200"
__proto__: Object
1:
department_course: "[{"course_code":"PHP101","course_title":"Introduction to Physics"},{"course_code":"PHP101d","course_title":"dkndk"},{"course_code":"PHP1091","course_title":"Introduction to House"}]"
department_name: "Department of BioChemistry"
id: 2
level: "300"

Comment: @emmadedayo Can you edit the valid (not truncated) `JSON` into your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base of you provided api respond

***respond example***

```
[{
  department_course: [{"course_code":"PHP101","course_title":"Introduction to Physics"}] ,
  department_name: "Department of Physics Electronics", 
  id: 1 ,
  level: "200"
} , 
]
```

***template***

```
<table id="responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>Courses</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dep of table_list" class="gradeX">
      <td>{{ dep.id}}</td>
      <td>{{ dep.department_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ dep.level }}</td>
      <td>
        <span*ngFor="let c of dep.department_course || []">
          {{c.course_code}}</span> , <span>{{c.course_title}}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Updated :**

solving this error ***NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.*** this can handle by the api or you can use [rxjs map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator  or create a method to solve this

*component*

```
parse(jsonString = '[]') { return JSON.parse(jsonString)};
```

*template*

```
  <span *ngFor="let c of parse(dep.department_course)">..</span>
```

> my recomandation is to use [rxjs map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator

Comment: `RROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[{"course_code":"PHP101","course_title":"Introduction to Physics"},{"course_code":"PHP101d","course_title":"dkndk"},{"course_code":"PHP1091","course_title":"Introduction to House"}]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck`

Comment: this related to your api , the api return the courses as string not json array so you need to use rxjs map to parse each property or create a method to parse this @emmadedayo

Comment: this work fine "parse(jsonString = '[]') { return JSON.parse(jsonString)};" but still displaying this error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch whole data of the table and try:

```
<table id="responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Courses</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let emp of table_list" class="gradeX">
        <td>{{emp_id}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.department}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.level}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="emp.department_course">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let c of emp.department_course">
            <span>{{c.course_code}}</span> , <span>{{c.course_title}}</span>
          </ng-container>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: and this also ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[{"course_code":"PHP101","course_title":"Introduction to Physics"},{"course_code":"PHP101d","course_title":"dkndk"},{"course_code":"PHP1091","course_title":"Introduction to House"}]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: EDITED please check now

Comment: 0:
department_course: "[{"course_code":"PHP101","course_title":"Introduction to Physics"},{"course_code":"PHP101d","course_title":"dkndk"},{"course_code":"PHP1091","course_title":"Introduction to House"}]"
department_name: "Department of Physics Electronics"
id: 1
level: "200"
__proto__: Object
1:
department_course: "[{"course_code":"PHP101","course_title":"Introduction to Physics"},{"course_code":"PHP101d","course_title":"dkndk"},{"course_code":"PHP1091","course_title":"Introduction to House"}]"
department_name: "Department of BioChemistry"
id: 2
level: "300"

Comment: Yea dhawal,if i put {{empty.department_course}} it will display all the data but just want to loop through the data display in list format

Comment: @bhavin before this I used forEach it's not work for him

Comment: @Dhawal you can't use foreach in html, can use only *ngFor

Comment: Yes, man I mean to say I used *ngIf but it does not work for emmandedayo

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
<td *ngIf="emp.department_course">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let c of emp.department_course">
        <span>{{c.course_code}}</span> , <span>{{c.course_title}}</span>
    </ng-container>
</td>
```

[Structural Directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)